# Trouble deleting directory, Java

Tags: java

In my `jUnit`, i have a following snippet:

```
private String  session = "/tmp/session/";
private File    f;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    f = new File(session);
    f.mkdir();
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    System.out.println("Directory deleted:   " + f.delete()); // always false
}
```

Meanwhile:

- Directory permissions are ok (`drwxr-xr-x`)
- Directory contains some files (`-rw-r--r--`)
- No ownership issues (Creator user deletes)

What would cause for `f.delete()` to fail? Is `f.delete()` an equivalent of `rm -rf` ?

Comment: @PaulTomblin No. Updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the API documentation for File.delete:

> ```
> delete
>
> public boolean delete()
> Deletes the file or directory denoted by this abstract pathname. If this pathname
> denotes a directory, then the directory must be empty in order to be deleted.
> Returns:
> true if and only if the file or directory is successfully deleted; false otherwise
> Throws:
> SecurityException - If a security manager exists and its SecurityManager.checkDelete(java.lang.String) method denies delete
> ```
>
> access to the file

Note the bit about the directory needing to be empty.

Comment: Sigh .. dir should be empty .. completely missed this. Will traverse and delete individual files. Thanks Paul

Comment: @Jam don't reinvent the wheel. Use a library as [Óscar suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11635778/139010).

Comment: @MattBall Even better! Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way to recursively delete a non-empty directory (and not reinvent the wheel in the process) is to use functionality from an existing library, say the [FileUtils.deleteQuietly()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#deleteQuietly%28java.io.File%29) method of Apache Commons' file utils which specifies that:

> If file is a directory, delete it and all sub-directories (...) A directory to be deleted does not have to be empty

Comment: Of course when deciding to use an existing library, you should consider what effect it might have on your WAR file size, start up time and licensing, but Apache Commons are generally nice and small, fast, and use a decent license.

Answer (score 3):

As said before, your directory needs to be empty before you delete it. There is a great tutorial [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-delete-directory-in-java/) that you should take a look at. You need to a `recursive delete` of the directory and all of its files, because the directory needs to be empty before you delete it.